# Redux and NextJS 13

Tags: redux, next.js, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I am trying to build NextJs app with 13th version of next and redux.
I found the way to pass redux provider in app, but I still don't understand next thing:
How can I use "createAsyncThunk" actions or RTK query with "getStaticProps" and another next functions for fetching data in nextJS 13 and app folder?

Answer (score 1):

createAsyncThunk used for async call, you can dispatch from your next js component like dispatch an action.

```
export async function getServerSideProps (context) {
      const rooms = await store.dispatch(getAlldata ()).unwrap();
      return { props: { rooms } }
    }
```

//AsyncThunk

```
export const getAlldata = createAsyncThunk('rooms/fetchData', async 
      (payload, thunkAPI) => {
  try {
    .......
  } catch (err) {
    return err
  }
})
```

Comment: see more from - https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk

Answer (score 0):

**USING NEXTJS PAGE ROUTER**

You can use, run

> `npm i next-redux-wrapper next-redux-cookie-wrapper`

next-redux-wrapper will wraps your your app and make your redux store be available both on the client and server side.

So when ever you use `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` you will also have access to your redux store. check their documentation [here](https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper)

As for next-redux-cookie-wrapper, this package will help if you want to persisit any of your redux store value on browser refresh E.g userToken. Check their documentation [here](https://github.com/bjoluc/next-redux-cookie-wrapper)

**USING NEXTJS APP ROUTER**

Same technique might apply as i mentioned in the Page router answer so you might have to investigate your self